# Facebook Graph API seems to only return old posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

All of a sudden the graph api only seems to be returning old posts.  Here is an example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22yankees%22&type=post

The latest post is from yesterday, that can't be right.

https://developers.facebook.com/live_status  is showing everything is OK, any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Try now! :)

Comment: It looks like it was having problems from 1/10/12 at about 3:00 PM ET until around noon on 1/11/12.  Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1):

I've verified your issue.  You should log it as a bug with Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) so they can investigate.  I could find no current bug relating to this.  This also may be a transient issue.